# Nginx error https . curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: ssl, nginx, curl, https

Nginx. I cant access my NodeJs app listening in port 3000 via https. I can do through http.
https://www.modelistas.tk:3000/api/status throws error. I tried with curl

Verbose output:

```
root@ip-172-31-50-215:/opt/letsencrypt# curl -v -k https://modelistas.tk:3000/api/status
*   Trying 72.44.61.151...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to modelistas.tk (72.44.61.151) port 3000 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

My configuration Nginx default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    
    # Añadimos que escuche en el puerto 443 SSL:
        listen 443 ssl;
    

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    # AGREGADO Carpeta raiz de este servidor :
    root /var/www/www.modelistas.tk/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm;

    # AGREGADO
    server_name www.modelistas.tk modelistas.tk;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #agregado
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    
    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
    }
    
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }
    
     # Configuracion del certificado SSL de letsencrypt

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/modelistas.tk/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/modelistas.tk/privkey.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        
         # Cipher Suites disponibles:
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Uso de grupo Diffie-Hellman
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        
    

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name modelistas.ml www.modelistas.tk;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, you do not have TLSv1.3 on the server. Update the nginx conf to support TLSv1.3.

> ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3;

Or you could specify that curl downgrades and uses TLSv1.2 (or whatever the server supports) via this option.

> --tlsv1.2

Also:

You are connecting to ssl / tls through port 3000. And there is no TLS on that port. Connect to 443 as that is what is configured.
check if you are behind a proxy

Comment: The first configuration not works. and the seconds, has the same error.  curl -v -k  --tlsv1.2 https://modelistas.tk:3000/api/status
Trying 72.44.61.151
TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to modelistas.tk (72.44.61.151) port 3000 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Connect to 443. You do not have TLS on 3000